# É possível utilizar sub grupos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Eu tenho um formulário e este tem três pares de datas de início/fim. Para cada par eu valido se ambas as datas são preenchidas ou nenhuma delas é preenchida, porque não é permitido a preencher a data de início e não a data de fim e vice-versa, além disso, eu não posso enviar o formulário sem pelo menos um dos pares preenchidos.

Imaginem o usuário inserir datas apenas em datas de início , mas nenhuma em datas de fim, eu tenho que mostrar-lhe três mensagens de erro, um para cada par. Mas se o usuário inserir nenhum dado, eu deveria mandar apenas uma mensagem de erro.

O problema é que existem quatro grupos, um para cada par e um para o formulário inteiro, em outras palavras, os três primeiros pares são subgrupos do maior.

Se eu colocar o grupo maior no meu código em último lugar, eu só recebo uma mensagem de erro se o usuário enviar um formulário em branco, mas só recebo uma mensagem de erro se o usuário entrar apenas as datas de início ou fim também. Se eu colocar o grupo maior em primeiro lugar, eu recebo três mensagens de erro quando o usuário entra apenas as datas de início, o que é certo, mas também recebo três mensagens de erro iguais se o usuário enviar um formulário vazio.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="msgErros"></div>
<form>
    <label for="dataInicialSolicitacao">Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o Inicial</label>
    <input type="text" class="data skipOrFillDatasSolicitacao atLeastOneRequired" id="dataInicialSolicitacao" value="" size="12" name="filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao" maxlength="10" />
    <label for="dataFinalSolicitacao">Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o Final</label>
    <input type="text" class="data skipOrFillDatasSolicitacao atLeastOneRequired" id="dataFinalSolicitacao" value="" size="12" name="filtro.dataFinalSolicitacao" maxlength="10" />
    <br />
    <label for="dataInicialLiberacao">Libera&ccedil;&atilde;o Inicial</label>
    <input type="text" class="data skipOrFillDatasLiberacao atLeastOneRequired" id="dataInicialLiberacao" value="" size="12" name="filtro.dataInicialLiberacao" maxlength="10" />
    <label for="dataFinalLiberacao">Libera&ccedil;&atilde;o Final</label>
    <input type="text" class="data skipOrFillDatasLiberacao atLeastOneRequired" id="dataFinalLiberacao" value="" size="12" name="filtro.dataFinalLiberacao" maxlength="10" />
    <br />
    <label for="dataInicialInternacao">Interna&ccedil;&atilde;o Inicial</label>
    <input type="text" class="data skipOrFillDatasInternacao atLeastOneRequired" id="dataInicialInternacao" value="" size="12" name="filtro.dataInicialInternacao" maxlength="10" />
    <label for="dataFinalInternacao">Interna&ccedil;&atilde;o Final</label>
    <input type="text" class="data skipOrFillDatasInternacao atLeastOneRequired" id="dataFinalInternacao" value="" size="12" name="filtro.dataFinalInternacao" maxlength="10" />
    <br />
    <button>Consultar</button>
    <button type="reset">Limpar</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".data").mask("99/99/9999").datepicker();

$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        "filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".skipOrFillDatasSolicitacao"],
            require_from_group: [2, ".atLeastOneRequired"]
        },
        "filtro.dataFinalSolicitacao": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".skipOrFillDatasSolicitacao"],
            require_from_group: [2, ".atLeastOneRequired"]
        },
        "filtro.dataInicialInternacao": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".skipOrFillDatasInternacao"],
            require_from_group: [2, ".atLeastOneRequired"]
        },
        "filtro.dataFinalInternacao": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".skipOrFillDatasInternacao"],
            require_from_group: [2, ".atLeastOneRequired"]
        },
        "filtro.dataInicialLiberacao": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".skipOrFillDatasLiberacao"],
            require_from_group: [2, ".atLeastOneRequired"]
        },
        "filtro.dataFinalLiberacao": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".skipOrFillDatasLiberacao"],
            require_from_group: [2, ".atLeastOneRequired"]
        }
    },
    groups: {
        datasSolicitacao: "filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao filtro.dataFinalSolicitacao",
        datasLiberacao: "filtro.dataInicialLiberacao filtro.dataFinalLiberacao",
        datasInternacao: "filtro.dataInicialInternacao filtro.dataFinalInternacao",
        todos: "filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao filtro.dataFinalSolicitacao filtro.dataInicialLiberacao filtro.dataFinalLiberacao filtro.dataInicialInternacao filtro.dataFinalInternacao"
    },
    errorContainer: "#msgErros ul",
    errorLabelContainer: "#msgErros",
    wrapper: "li"
});
```

Criei um [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgioseffi/LevK6/5/) com o grupo maior no final. Para testá-lo basta digitar datas de início e pressionar "Consultar", você só vai ter uma mensagem quando eu preciso de três. Em seguida, pressione "Limpar" e depois "Consultar" e você terá uma mensagem apenas o que é correto.

E aqui está uma variação do primeiro [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgioseffi/LevK6/6/) com o grupo maior no começo. Para testá-lo basta digitar datas de início e pressione "Consultar", você vai ter três mensagens, uma para cada linha e isso é correto. Em seguida, pressione "Limpar" e depois "Consultar" e você receberá três mensagens e isso não é correto.

Alguma idéia para tornar o comportamento correto ocorre para ambos os casos?

Eu uso jQuery Validate 1.11.1 com jQuery 1.11.0.

Comment: Eu vi sua pergunta no meta e seu post em inglês no SO. Sugestão: tente simplificar mais o código antes de postar aqui. Se você conseguir criar um exemplo mínimo para explicar o problema, fica mais fácil das pessoas ajudarem, pois não precisam ler e entender um código maior. Bônus: no processo de tentar criar esse exemplo, muitas vezes acabamos descobrindo a solução sozinhos.

Comment: Entendi, vou tirar muita coisa que não tem absolutamente nada com o meu problema tipo o reset do form, as regras ignoradas, tirar o datepicker que não influencia no problema e aí consequentemente o onfocusout e etc. Obrigado pelo toque. Em tempo, você conseguiu olhar os fiddles? Tem idéia de qual possa ser o problema? E parabéns por correlacionar essas duas perguntas com a que eu fiz no meta, raciocínio rápido e lógico.

Comment: Recebi um warning sobre isso, mas não soube como corrigir. Valeu pela orientação! Em tempo, por que devemos fazer desse jeito?

Comment: Não consegui olhar direito o código porque era muito grande :)

Comment: Não tire o datepicker, pode dar jeito... E já agora, para usar links do github, retire o primeiro `.` (ponto). Assim use: `https://rawgithub.com/digitalBush/` em vez de `raw.github` __http://jsfiddle.net/LevK6/2/__

Comment: Acerca do `git`, dê uma olhada aqui: https://rawgithub.com/

Comment: Entendi sobre o git e já estou editando meu código aqui e nos dois fiddles.

Comment: @bfavaretto código na pergunta e no fiddle modificado de acordo com as suas instruções. Está melhor agora?

Comment: Ficou melhor sim! Espero que apareça uma resposta, eu infelizmente não conheço o jq.validate bem o suficiente para ajudar,

Comment: De qualquer maneira ajudou bastante em outros aspectos, @bfavaretto.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu consegui entender a sua pergunta, essa aqui seria a sua resposta:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LevK6/8/)

**Eu retirei o grupo:**

```js
datasSolicitacao: "filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao filtro.dataFinalSolicitacao",
datasLiberacao: "filtro.dataInicialLiberacao filtro.dataFinalLiberacao",
datasInternacao: "filtro.dataInicialInternacao filtro.dataFinalInternacao"
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas a retirada do grupo não resolveu meu problema. o comportamente incluso por você está correto quando o usuário tenta enviar o formulário sem preencher nada, pois aparece apenas uma mensagem. Mas imagine o usuário inserindo apenas datas de início, ao pressionar consultar eu quero que apareça três mensagens de erro pra ele, informando que ele precisa preencher as datas finais de onde ele já preencheu a inicial ou apagar a data inicial.